# Conditional fillna() in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two below dataframes `df1` and `df2`

df1:

```
A   B       C       D
1   Nora    NaN     Japan
2   Neo     NaN     India
3   Nord    NaN     Fuji
4   Noman   2020    Unknown
```

df2:

```
E       F
1123    Neo
1124    Norm
1126    Nora
```

I need to perform a fillna in `df1` and take values from `df2` only for those values which have entries in `df2`.

Resultant Dataframe:
df1:

```
A   B       C       D
1   Nora    1126    Japan
2   Neo     1123    India
3   Nord    NaN     Fuji
4   Noman   2020    Unknown
```

Is there any way for the same? I do not want to loop since I have huge dataframe which might decrease the performance of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set column `F` as index in  second df2 then use that as mapping using `pd.Series.map` then use it as fill value.

```
mapping = df2.set_index('F').squeeze()
df1['C'] = df1['C'].fillna(df['B'].map(mapping))

   A      B       C        D
0  1   Nora  1126.0    Japan
1  2    Neo  1123.0    India
2  3   Nord     NaN     Fuji
3  4  Noman  2020.0  Unknown
```